# How to convert an email address into a MD5 hash on Zapier?

Tags: node.js, zapier

In order to use Gravatar profile images, I'd like to convert an email address to an MD5 hash (which Gravatar requires).

Zapier allows the use of Node 4.3.2.

Who can help?

Answer (score 1):

Use the `crypto` module that comes standard with Node 4.3.2.

```
var crypto = require('crypto');
var emailStr = 'your@email.com';
var hashStr = crypto.createHash('md5').update(emailStr).digest('hex');
```

Comment: Thanks! This works, but for some reason the generated hash, added to the gravatar URL (https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/HASH) won't produce images.

Since gravatar doesn't have a way to validate (afaik) I can't be sure whether the hash is wrong or if the email has no gravatar image.

Comment: Likely there is no Gravatar in that case.

Comment: Hey Bryan, could you help with this answer please ? https://stackoverflow.com/q/47837434/2940051

Answer (score -1):

You could use the https://github.com/coolaj86/jsMD5

```
var md5 = require('./md5')
  , na
  , str
  ;

na = md5.digest(<array of numbers>);
// na is an array of numbers

str = md5.digest_s('The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog.');
// str === '5c6ffbdd40d9556b73a21e63c3e0e904'
```