# How to use the post_poll method in Zapier CLI

Tags: zapier-cli

According to the [docs](https://zapier.com/developer/documentation/v2/app-checks-reference/#ZDE009), I should use a `post_poll` function to add the missing `id` field in the response.

How do I add the post_poll function ?

Here's my error:

> Results must be an array, got: object,
>   ({"totalevents":83,"events":[{"eventid":10266033,"c)
>     - Got a result missing the "id" property (83)

Tried following [this](https://github.com/zapier/zapier-platform-legacy-scripting-runner) but it is not clear to me, I'm very new to Zapier-CLI

### Update - adding code

This is the function that returns the data:

```
const listEvents = (z, bundle) => {

    console.log('listing events.. ');
    let client_id = bundle.inputData.client_id;
    const requestOpts = {
        url: `https://wccqa.on24.com/wcc/api/v2/client/${client_id}/event`  
    };

    return z.request(requestOpts)
            .then((response) => {
                return z.JSON.parse(response.content);
            });
};
```

The sample response is the following, with the distiction that I added the `id` param manually to avoid errors when `zapier test|push`:

```
{
    "id": 9964513,
    "eventid": 9964513,
    "archivestart": "2017-09-21T10:30:00-07:00",
    "archiveend": "2018-09-21T10:30:00-07:00",
    "description": "Zapier Event Test",
    "iseliteexpired": "N",
    "displaytimezonecd": "America/Bogota",
    "eventtype": "Live Webcam ",
    "regrequired": true,
    "clientid": 22921,
    "liveend": "2017-09-21T10:00:00-07:00",
    "createtimestamp": "2017-09-21T09:47:44-07:00",
    "audienceurl": "https://localhost.on24.com/wcc/r/9964513/C49755A02229BD48E6010848D7C81EF8",
    "lastmodified": "2017-09-21T09:47:44-07:00",
    "livestart": "2017-09-21T08:45:00-07:00",
    "goodafter": "2017-09-21T09:00:00-07:00",
    "regnotificationrequired": true,
    "isactive": true,
    "localelanguagecd": "en"
}
```

The **ACTUAL** response from the endpoint the following which is used in the app created in the Web Builder App instead of CLI and works fine:

```
{
    "events": [
        {
            "eventid": 9964513,
            "archivestart": "2017-09-21T10:30:00-07:00",
            "archiveend": "2018-09-21T10:30:00-07:00",
            "description": "Zapier Event Test",
            "iseliteexpired": "N",
            "displaytimezonecd": "America/Bogota",
            "eventtype": "Live Webcam ",
            "regrequired": true,
            "clientid": 22921,
            "liveend": "2017-09-21T10:00:00-07:00",
            "createtimestamp": "2017-09-21T09:47:44-07:00",
            "audienceurl": "https://localhost.on24.com/wcc/r/9964513/C49755A02229BD48E6010848D7C81EF8",
            "lastmodified": "2017-09-21T09:47:44-07:00",
            "livestart": "2017-09-21T08:45:00-07:00",
            "goodafter": "2017-09-21T09:00:00-07:00",
            "regnotificationrequired": true,
            "isactive": true,
            "localelanguagecd": "en"
        }
    ],
    "totalevents": 1
}
```

I was thinking something along the line of the following, but how do I register this ?

```
const postPoll = (event,z,bundle) => {

    if(event.key === 'events'){

        var results = z.JSON.parse(bundle.request.data).results;

        var events = results.events.map(function(event){
                              event.id = event.eventid;
                              return event;
                            });     

        bundle.request.data = events;
    }
};

module.exports = postPoll;
```

Comment: just to clarify, you're working on a [CLI app](https://github.com/zapier/zapier-platform-cli), correct? The second thing you linked to only pertains to converted web builder apps.

Comment: Hey @xavdid - yes, CLI

Comment: great! can you update your question with the code for your function? That'll help me direct you more specifically. The bottom line is that your function needs to return an array, not a single object.

Comment: @xavdid question updated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nice, so you're almost there! CLI apps don't have `pre_` and `post_` poll methods. Instead, you put any manipulation after the response comes in.

```js
const listEvents = (z, bundle) => {
console.log('listing events.. ');
let client_id = bundle.inputData.client_id;
const requestOpts = {
    url: `https://wccqa.on24.com/wcc/api/v2/client/${client_id}/event`  
};

return z.request(requestOpts)
        .then((response) => {
            return z.JSON.parse(response.content);
        })
        .then(data => {
            const events = data.events; // array of events
            return events.map(function(e){ // returns array of objects with `id` defined
                e.id = e.event_id
                return e
            }) 
        })
};
```

Comment: Excelent! Thank you very much. Sorry to bother so much but, how do I solve the following error when running  `zapier test` locally ?  `Error: Timeout of 2000ms exceeded. For async tests and hooks, ensure "done()" is called; if returning a Promise, ensure it resolves`

Comment: hard to tell for sure without seeing the code, but make sure you return the `AppTester` call or write more explicit tests and call `done()`, like the message says. See [the docs](https://github.com/zapier/zapier-platform-cli#writing-unit-tests).

Comment: I'll create a new question and pass the link jejej